# Swift - addsubviews at fixed position for move, rotate and scale

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIWebView and I am adding subviews to it like so:

```
self.webview.addSubview(uiviewexample)
```

now I am looking for away to have this uiviewexample to have a fixed position so when I move, rotate or scale the uiwebview, the uiviewexample is contained with the uiwebview.

I have tried adding the uiviewexample like so

```
self.webview.window!.addSubview(uiexampleview)
```

but that did absolutely nothing.

My problem is, I may have one uiexampleview or 10, I just don't know, so I am looking for away to do this for all subviews in my uiwebview.

Is this possible?

Comment: Well what exactly happens to the uiviewexample when yiu move/scale/rotate the webview?